# How to add insert option Programmatically in C# Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore8, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Insert option is not coming, can anyone help on this how I can programmatically insert option with item when we do not have insert option in _standardValue of template

Answer (score 1):

When you create/edit the item from code, you can at the same time write to the *Insert Options* field, aka `__Masters` as field name, aka `Branches` as code constant, just as any other field. The field contains a pipe-separated list of template ID's. For example, like this:

```
item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Branches] = "{TemplateId1}|{TemplateId2}|{...}";
// above is equivalent to item["__Masters"] = "...";
```

As you say, this will write a local value on the item being edited, and will therefore break any inheritance of the insert options that may be defined in `__Standard Values`. But in some scenarios this is actually better than having it on `__Standard Values`.